# How to find duplicates in Pandas Dataframe based upon certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe,

```
RTYPE  PERIOD_ID    STORE_ID                       MKT MTYPE  RGROUP  RZF  RXF
0    MKT   20171411  3102300001  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
1    MKT   20171411  3102300002  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
2    MKT   20171411  3104001193              PM Provision  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
3    MKT   20171411  3104001193  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
4    MKT   20171411  3104001193    Provision including MM  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
5    MKT   20171411  3104001641              PM Provision  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
6    MKT   20171411  3104001641  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
7    MKT   20171411  3104001641    Provision including MM  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
8    MKT   20171411  3104001682              PM Provision  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
9    MKT   20171411  3104001682  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
10   MKT   20171411  3104001682    Provision including MM  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
11   MKT   20171412  3104001682                   Alcohol  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
12   MKT   20171412  3104001682                      Fish  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
13   MKT   20171412  3104001684                   Alcohol  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
14   MKT   20171412  3104001684                      Fish  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I need to find the duplicate MKT's based upon this condition,
if the set of store id's is exactly the same for MKTs in that particular period_id then those MKTs are duplicate.
So in this case for
Period 20171411, Duplicates are PM Provision and Provision including MM, and
for period 20171412 , Duplicates are Alcohol and Fish.

I have tried this till now:-

```
df1 = newdf[newdf.duplicated(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID'], keep=False)]
d1 = {k:tuple(set(v)) for k, v in df1.groupby('PERIOD_ID')['MKT']}
print (d1)
```

Which is returning:-

```
{20171411L: ('Provision including MM', 'PM Provision', 'PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO'), 20171412L: ('Fish', 'Alcohol')}
```

The above output isn't returning the duplicates but only the unique set of MKTS for that period.

What I need is something like this in which I have the periods as Keys and Duplicate MKTs for that period as values. The condition for being duplicates is mentioned above in the post -

```
{20171411L: ('Provision including MM', 'PM Provision'), 20171412L: ('Fish', 'Alcohol')}
```

I am really new to Pandas and have some basic understanding of python. 
Any help will be great.

Comment: Have you tried to group by this conditions ?

Comment: I have used  group by, not sure how to group by for that particular condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the following code

```
    df1=df[['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID','MKT']]
    df1=df1.sort_values(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID'],ascending=True)
    duplicatedf = df1.groupby(['PERIOD_ID','MKT'])['STORE_ID'].agg(lambda STORE_ID: ','.join(STORE_ID.astype(str).replace(' ','').unique())).reset_index()
    duplicates =duplicatedf[ duplicatedf.duplicated(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID'],keep='first') | duplicatedf.duplicated(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID'],keep='last')]
    duplicates= duplicates.groupby(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID']).agg(lambda MKT: ','.join(MKT.astype(str))).reset_index()
    print (duplicates)


#Converting the df into dict
    dupdictdf=duplicates[['PERIOD_ID','MKT']]
    dicta=dupdictdf.to_dict("records")
    print (dicta)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood you correctly, feel free to comment if I forgot something or didn't understand correctly.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID','MKT'],
                    as_index=False)\
                    .agg({'MTYPE':'count'})\
                    .rename(columns={'MTYPE': 'count'})

df_grouped[df_grouped['count'] > 1]\
           .groupby('PERIOD_ID')\
           .agg({'MKT':lambda x: list(set(x))}).to_dict()['MKT']
```

Comment: The column name isn't 'MKT MTYPE, it is just 'MKT', 'MTYPE' is a different column in the df. Also, the expected output is `{20171411L: ('Provision including MM', 'PM Provision'), 20171412L: ('Fish', 'Alcohol')}` where they keys are the period_ids and the values are duplicate MKT's for that period

Comment: Oh I see, fixed the MKT column.
Also it is now in dict output, I hope that this is what you wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your condition. I just removed the unique MKTs present from the duplicate MKTs you found.

```
duplicate = {k:set(v) for k, v in newdf[newdf.duplicated(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID'], 
                                                         keep=False)].groupby('PERIOD_ID')['MKT']}
unique = {k:set(v) for k, v in newdf[newdf.duplicated(['PERIOD_ID','STORE_ID'], 
                                                      keep=False) == False].groupby('PERIOD_ID')['MKT']}

final = dict()
for k in duplicate:
    if k in unique:
        final[k] = tuple(duplicate[k] - unique[k])
    else:
        final[k] = tuple(duplicate[k])

print(final)
```